# MySQL return based on a difference

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to run a query to return the customer first and last name only if the IP address they have used for a session is different.

for example:

```
Customer 1 makes Order on Session IP address: 192.168.12.1
Customer 1 makes Order on Session IP address: 192.168.12.2

Customer 2 makes Order on Session IP address: 192.168.12.3
Customer 2 makes Order on Session IP address: 192.168.12.3

Return Customer where IP address is not same (Customer 1)
```

However, I can't work out how to specify the difference in the IP address.

What I currently have is:

```
Select Cust_First, Cust_Last
FROM customer

LEFT join Session
On customer.cust_ID = session.Cust_ID

LEFT join Order
On session.Ses_ID = order.Session_ID

Where Ses_IPAddress # Is different for the same customer?
```

I'll detail the tables with the necessary fields:

```
Customer:
PK: Cust_ID
row: Cust_First
row: Cust_Last

Session:
PK: Ses_ID
FK: Cust_ID
Row: Ses_IPAddress

Order:
PK: Order_ID
FK Ses_ID
```

Comment: my $0.02 - try group by `Ses_IPAddress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the task is way easier than the way you are trying to complete it. Just select these customers from the ones that do fit your logic.

```
SELECT Cust_First, Cust_Last
FROM Customer
WHERE Cust_ID IN (
    SELECT Cust_ID
    FROM Session
    JOIN Order On Session.Ses_ID = Order.Ses_ID
    GROUP BY Cust_ID, Session.Ses_IPAddress 
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
```

Comment: It's returning items, but it doesn't work out if the IP address is different? 

Only if they've used multiple IPAddress?

Comment: Your question is unclear on the part "IP address is different". What do you mean by that? Different from what? Please provide an example and then I will try to adjust my query. And yeah, currently the result of the query does exactly what you said in this comment.

Comment: Okay, I mean so, if a customer has made an order on 'Ip address: a' and 'ip address b' return those customers first and last name?

At the minute it returns the first and last name even if an order takes the ipaddress from 'ip address: a' and at another time 'ip address: a'

I really hope that's better?

Comment: You should have made an example at the very beginning and saved us both much time. Go update your question with a proper example, please. Best if you could give two examples: one user that needs to be taken and the other that doesn't :)

Comment: What does my query return then in that case? Maybe Drew Pierce's solution is working?

Comment: I returns the first and last name of the people with more than one session IP address, whether it is the same or different. 

I am now playing around with Drew Pierce's soltuion, to me it makes a little more sense, though playing with the data and trying to get it to output what I want isn't quite working. If the person has 4 sessions all with the same IP address it still returns that persons first and last name.

Comment: Now I understand :) I will try to check if I can fix it. By the way, what probably confused me the most is that Cust_ID is on Session table and not on order table. Does that mean several users can edit one order?

Comment: The idea is, a customer can have multiple session. That session can then make multiple orders before the session ends. An order is made up of the items to be sold, the session that that order was made in and a delivery type. In text it doesn't quite make sense, but on a diagram I think it does.

If you were curious, this is the schema with that in http://tinypic.com/r/nlu2h0/6

Comment: What if you change into `GROUP BY Cust_ID, Session.Ses_ID, Session.Ses_IPAddress`? Did that help?

Comment: That doesn't return anything when I do that.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31fbd/3 Please edit the data if I misunderstood your example :) Once you're done and added a link, I will try again. Might happen a bit later in the evening tho :/

Answer (score 1):

Can't predict without seeing source data and output. May be this?

```
Select customer.Cust_First, customer.Cust_Last
FROM customer

LEFT join session
On customer.Cust_ID = session.Cust_ID

LEFT join order
On session.Ses_ID = order.Session_ID

GROUP BY customer.Cust_ID, session.Ses_IPAddress
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: COUNT(*) will cause you trouble because it will try to reference fields that are not in a `GROUP BY`

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I thought count in having clause only matters for groupings that result out of the group by clause.

Comment: I am not 100% about this one and most likely you are right, but I remember queries where COUNT(*) was acting up, so I just got used to not using that asterix :)